# If we move from one point to another with constant speed/velocity will the work done be zero or not?

Tags: energy, kinematics, work, velocity

We know that work done is change in kinetic energy, but when the speed is constant the work done must be zero, I guess. Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in saying that the work performed on an object with constant velocity is 0. The work-energy theorem says that the net work done on an object equals change in its kinetic energy.
$$
W_{net} = \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \mathbf F_{net} \cdot \mathrm d \mathbf x = KE(t_f) - KE(t_i)
$$

For an object with constant velocity, $KE(t_f) = KE(t_i)$ and thus $W_{net} = 0$.

In a lot of cases, however, what you want to calculate is not the *net* work performed on an object, but the work done *by* some agent, that is, by some force.

For example, in a lift ascending upwards or a block sliding on a rough floor at constant velocity, the net work is zero. Let us call the force of gravity in the first case and the force of friction in the second, the resistive force $F_{res}$, and the force opposed to it the applied force $F_{app}$.

In both cases we will likely be interested in the work done by $F_{app}$, which will be nonzero. The work done by $F_{app}$ is what is converted into potential energy in the first case and dissipated through friction in the second.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious counterexample is a lift moving upwards at constant velocity. The lift does work on its occupants because it increases their gravitational potential energy. So moving at constant velocity does not necessarily mean no work is done.

Although it's true that work can go into kinetic energy it can also go into potential energy. In the example I give the potential energy is gravitational, but this isn't the only possibility. Suppose I have a mass on the end of a spring and I pull the mass at a constant speed, extending the spring in the process. In this case I do work and that work goes into the elastic energy in the spring.

For any process the work is defined by the integral:

$$ W = \int \mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf x $$

where $F$ is the force exerted and $x$ is the position. To calculate the work done on an object it is the force that matters.

Answer (score 0):

If we are inside a system where the pressure is exactly zero (no air resistance because of the vacuum) and if the surface on which we are moving is absolutely frictionless, no work will be done provided that the velocity of our body does not change and the distance from the earth's center remains constant.